# feedback on my table

Tags: tables

I have created a table, inspired by this guide: http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf

Here is my result

```
\begin{table}[tp]%
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule%
&Table &Light [L]  &$\zeta_0/2\pi$ [MHz]  &Flux [1/s]  &Dimensions [m] \\\toprule
&10    &3          &28.73                 &asd         &$(20\times 10)$ \\
&1     &3          &28.73                 &asd         &$(20\times 10)$ \\
&0     &3          &28.73                 &asd         &$(20\times 10)$ \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maximum load and nominal tension.}
\label{aggiungi}
\end{table}
```

I would like to hear what other people think of it. Personally I would like the distance beween the headlines and the lower toprule to be a little larger, but I'm not quite sure how to do that properly.

Any feedback and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use  `\midrule` between the heading and the data rows, rather than a `\toprule`.

Comment: Hi Niles1710373. Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: It's not entirely clear if the unit of the product `$20\times10$` is metre or sqare metre. I'm guessing it's the latter?

Comment: It is 20m times 10m. Is my notation unclear? Do you have any suggestions for what i can change it to?

Comment: Maybe something like `[$\unit{m}\times\unit{m}$]` (with an appropriate definition of `\unit` or even better using [`siunitx`](http://wwwmctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and its `\si` which is a good idea anyway if you need units more often)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the dimensions in an own row to save some horizontal space which gives a better looking tabular:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Maximum load and nominal tension.}\label{aggiungi}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc>{$}c<{$}@{}}\toprule
Table &Light  &$\zeta_0/2\pi$ &Flux   &\mbox{Dimensions}  \\
      &[L]    & [MHz]         &[1/s]  &\mbox{[m]} \\\midrule
10    &3      &28.73          &asd    &(20\times 10) \\
1     &3      &28.73          &asd    &(20\times 10) \\
0     &3      &28.73          &asd    &(20\times 10) \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing the second midrule to a toprule, but then the distance between the units and lower toprule is decreased a little. Do you know how i can increase it?

Comment: use `\midrule[1pt]` instead

Answer (score 7):

You have a column too much. Moreover, units should be specified in parentheses, rather than (square) brackets, which mean a different thing (abstract dimensions and not units).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}    
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format=2.2]cc}
\toprule
Table & Light    & {$\zeta_0/2\pi$} & Flux          & Dimensions     \\
      & (\si{L}) & {(\si{MHz})}     & (\si{s^{-1}}) & (\si{m})       \\
\midrule
10    & 3        & 28.73            & asd           &$(20\times 10)$ \\
1     & 3        & 28.73            & asd           &$(20\times 10)$ \\
0     & 3        & 28.73            & asd           &$(20\times 10)$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maximum load and nominal tension.}
\label{aggiungi}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Using `siunitx` ensures uniform appearance of your units and also gives many tools for table processing.

I'm a bit dubious about the parentheses in the last column.

[image]

Comment: For the last column's units `(\si{m} \times \si{m})` would make it dimensionally consistent without obscuring the dimensions by turning it into `\si{\square\m}`.

Comment: @Ricardo Yes, I agree; but it also depends on the traditions in the field where this is used (which I don't know).